# How to create small window (32x32) on Windows?

Tags: windows, winapi, createwindow

Here is how the window was created. But when I GetClientRect, the rcClient is much bigger than 32x32.

```
int nDefaultWidth = 32;
int nDefaultHeight = 32;

UINT32 winStyle = 0;

RECT rc;
SetRect( &rc, 0, 0, nDefaultWidth, nDefaultHeight );
AdjustWindowRect( &rc, winStyle, ( hMenu != NULL ) ? true : false );


// Create the render window
HWND hWnd = CreateWindow( L"Direct3DWindowClass", NULL, winStyle,
                          x, y, ( rc.right - rc.left ), ( rc.bottom - rc.top ), 0,
                          hMenu, hInstance, 0 );

RECT rcClient;
GetClientRect( hWnd, &rcClient );
```

Answer (score 2):

You are passing `0` as the `dwStyle` parameter to [`AdjustWindowRect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632665%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). That value is equal to [`WS_OVERLAPPED`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632600%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#ws_overlapped), and `AdjustWindowRect` explicitly forbids you to pass that specific value.

Since you want to create a 32x32 window (i.e. with no chrome at all, pure client area) you should lose the `AdjustWindowRect` call as it serves no purpose at all and pass `WS_POPUP` as the window style to `CreateWindow`.